# Internet Explorer and Chrome are not accepting my cookie

Tags: .net, asp.net, cookies, cross-browser

In my website, I returns a cookie in this way:

```
context.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("MYCOOKIE", MyStringVar) 
{ 
 HttpOnly = false, 
 Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(GlobalSettings.AuthCookieDuration) 
});
```

In development, everything works good in all browsers, but when I deploy the app to a server, only Firefox is able to log in (so it's the only one accepting the cookie). In the server, the app runs on the root of the server, there is not virtual path.

What could be the problem?

Many thanks.

EDIT:

I've looked at it wit Fiddler, and the server is returning the cookie, no doubt. So the problem is that Chrome and IE are not accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that the server had a wrong GMT time, so it was sending back a cookie already outdated, and the browser of course, was dropping it :P

Today is Fri 28 Jan 2011 12:50 GMT, and the server was returning a time from yesterday!!

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 27 Jan 2011 23:12:15 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
p3p: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Location: http://myserver
Set-Cookie: AUTH=jll+9[...]; expires=Thu, 27-Jan-2011 23:32:15 GMT; path=/
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 166
```

Happy days :)

Fiddler is a great tool ;)